# Does Minitest Have A Version Of RSpec's Anything?

Tags: ruby, minitest

In RSpec I can do `mock_obj.should_receive(:method).with(anything)...` where 'anything' is any variable.

Can I do this in Minitest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest), since it's included to Ruby 1.9, provides `MiniTest::Spec`, a contextual RSpec like syntax. It's not RSpec.

From the Github Page, this is what [Minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest) provides

> - minitest/autorun - the easy and explicit way to run all your tests.
> - minitest/unit - a very fast, simple, and clean test system.
> - minitest/spec - a very fast, simple, and clean spec system.
> - minitest/mock - a simple and clean mock/stub system.
> - minitest/benchmark - an awesome way to assert your algorithm's performance.
> - minitest/pride - show your pride in testing!
> - Incredibly small and fast runner, but no bells and whistles.

To do the same than `mock_obj.should_receive(:method).with(anything)`, you'll write

require 'minitest/autorun'

```
describe YourClass do
  it 'should receive a call to method' do
    mock_obj = Minitest::Mock.new
    mock_obj.expect(:method, :your_return, [anything])
    # ...
    mock_obj.verify # verify that the expected call has been made
  end
end
```